# C++ Multiple parameters with GTest TYPED_TEST

Tags: c++, googletest

I have fallowing sets of tests:

```
TEST_F(FactoryShould, createAFromAModule)
{
    const auto stateMachine = createStateMachine(EModule_A);
    const auto* typedStateMachine =
        dynamic_cast<const BackEnd<transitiontable::A, Guard>*>(stateMachine.get());
    ASSERT_TRUE(typedStateMachine);
}

TEST_F(FactoryShould, createBFromBModule)
{
    const auto stateMachine = createStateMachine(EModule_B);
    const auto* typedStateMachine =
        dynamic_cast<const BackEnd<transitiontable::B, Guard>*>(stateMachine.get());
    ASSERT_TRUE(typedStateMachine);
}
```

Is there any way to turn them into Typed Tests? All I seen is solution for only one changing parameter, there I have 2 changing parameters, EModule can be used for multiple transitiontables, so something like map looks good, but it is doable?

Comment: In your case the two types are connected - you would always change them together. You could create a wrapper type in the test code that inside it contains typedefs to the 2 types you need to instantiate.

Comment: bu this do You mean something like this:
struct Type
{
using EModule = ::testing::Types<EModule_A, EModule_B>;
using transition = ::testing::Types<transitiontable::A, transitiontable::B>;
}

in TC it looks good (if it will work that way) but it looks hard to maintenance

TEST_F(FactoryShould, createFromModule)
{
    const auto stateMachine = createStateMachine(Type.EModule);
    const auto* typedStateMachine =
        dynamic_cast<const BackEnd<Type.transition, Guard>*>(stateMachine.get());
    ASSERT_TRUE(typedStateMachine);
}

Comment: I think so, but as you can see, comments don't work for formatting code.
I'm not sure which maintenence issue you have: creating a new variant, or adding a third helper class. For the former you might be able to create a class template with the two classes as arguments, and create that class on the fly. For the latter, updating the template may be acceptable. You could look at template tuples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) you can
make one type out of any other two. (And with [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)
you can make one type out of any other *N*).

You can write googletest `TYPED_TEST`s in which `TypeParam` assumes values from
a list of `std::pair<X,Y>`, for paired parameter-types `X` and `Y`, so that each instantiation of such a `TYPED_TEST`
has `X` defined as `TypeParam::first_type` and `Y` defined as `TypeParam::second_type`. E.g:

**gtester.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <utility>
#include <cctype>

struct A1 {
    char ch = 'A';
};

struct A2 {
    char ch = 'a';
};

struct B1 {
    char ch = 'B';
};

struct B2 {
    char ch = 'b';
};


template <typename T>
class pair_test : public ::testing::Test {};

using test_types = ::testing::Types<std::pair<A1,A2>, std::pair<B1,B2>>;
TYPED_TEST_CASE(pair_test, test_types);

TYPED_TEST(pair_test, compare_no_case)
{
    typename TypeParam::first_type param1;
    typename TypeParam::second_type param2;
    ASSERT_TRUE(param1.ch == std::toupper(param2.ch));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile, link, run:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o gtester gtester.cpp -lgtest -pthread && ./gtester
[==========] Running 2 tests from 2 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from pair_test/0, where TypeParam = std::pair<A1, A2>
[ RUN      ] pair_test/0.compare_no_case
[       OK ] pair_test/0.compare_no_case (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from pair_test/0 (0 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from pair_test/1, where TypeParam = std::pair<B1, B2>
[ RUN      ] pair_test/1.compare_no_case
[       OK ] pair_test/1.compare_no_case (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from pair_test/1 (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 2 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```